# What to do with the [processing] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

Currently [processing](/questions/tagged/processing) contains 796 questions. The tag describes itself as

> Processing is an open source programming language ...

The questions are either really about the *Processing* language or about an algorythm in general that should process something.

This tag is really problematic since most people don't know that there is a programming language called *Processing* (I did not). And well, processing is what all programs do.

There were 2 other questions regarding that tag in the past:
[what tag for processing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50751/what-tag-for-processing) and 
[tag synonym request processing.org -> processing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110888/tag-synonym-request-processing-org-processing)

So what should be done about that tag?

Answer (score 6):

We should change [processing](/questions/tagged/processing) to [processing-language](/questions/tagged/processing-language), and move the tag wiki over. (The tag wiki should be moved either way, so I'll propose that edit.) That way, all the irrelevant questions are filtered out and retagged. At that point, the [processing](/questions/tagged/processing) tag should either be deleted or blacklisted for being too general. But that's its own question.

Still, I agree. Processing is simply too generic.

Comment: I agree - [processing] ought to be blacklisted or deleted, and have everything moved to [processing-language]. Hopefully that will reduce the vagueness of the tag, and discourage improper use.

Comment: Well... not everything. We need to look at each question individually to see if it actually *belongs* in [processing]. Most of them actually don't even belong there.